# Partioning train and test data in a time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation

I have a monthly time series data from 2013 to 2020, Is it safe to do a fixed partioning where I train on 2013 to 2018 then use 2019 to 2020 as my test data? I am just scared that the will be a data leakage on Model (Arima) for data 2019 to 2020 as some of the underlying effects wont be captured for 2019 to 2020. These might affect the forecasing perfomance. In this case what do I do? do I train on the whole data or?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  To predict 2021, model the years you have or something less?  One approach is to use 2013-18 to predict 2019 &20.  If the predict matches the data, use that model and use all of your data to predict 2021&22.